# Python printing None in result , Why?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand Classes in python.

Question: Why I am getting None in the output?

Here is my code :

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def show_student(self):
        print("Student Name:", self.name)
        print("Student Age: ", self.age)


first_student = Student("amit", 12)
print(first_student.show_student())
```

And here is the output.

```
C:\Python38\python.exe D:/LearningRoot/DirFirst/test.py
Student Name: amit
Student Age:  12
None
```

Comment: Because `first_student.show_student()` *returns `None`*, and you print the return value of `first_student.show_student()`

Comment: This has *nothing to do with* classes. You can equally well cause the same problem with ordinary functions. You should make sure you understand those fundamentals before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first_student.show_student()` returns `None`, which is what all Python functions return if no explicit return value was specified. Therefore:

```
print(first_student.show_student())
```

This will evaluate to `print(None)`.

Comment: "first_student.show_student() does not return anything." - it *does* return something. It returns `None`, like all functions that don't have an explicit return value.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Indeed, I misspoke here, thanks for the correction. Edited the answer accordingly.